# reload view of invisible controller through notification center broadcasting objective c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, xcode9

I have two controller in my screen and want to reload one method when push notification receive.

Now question is that listener successfully call when visible specific controller via `NSNotificationCenter`. But when i am on another controller then listener method not call.

Can i handle it via `NSNotificationCenter`? If no then what is the best approach for this? Thanks.

Comment: try it- if you already did show your code

Comment: In code just broadcasting and then listener receive it. No any other functionality.